# cameraOverlayView not applying

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera

When I try and apply a cameraOverlayView to UIImagePickerController, it doesn't show up. I have read through some documentation on how to apply this, and my code all looks correct. If someone could explain why my overlay isn't starting, I would really appriciate it.

```
//Start the camera up

UIImagePickerController *imageViewPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

//Hide default UI elements

imageViewPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imageViewPickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
imageViewPickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
imageViewPickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

//Start the button overlay

UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewPickerController.view.bounds];
btnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
btnView.alpha = 0.3;
btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;

//Add a button to the overlay

UIButton *snapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)];
snapButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[btnView addSubview:snapButton];

//Overlay button view

imageViewPickerController.cameraOverlayView = btnView;

//Fix for iPhone 5 and make fullscreen

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -55.0);
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.333333, 1.333333);
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(180));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translate, scale);
transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, rotate);
imageViewPickerController.cameraViewTransform = transform;

//Let's present it all

[self presentViewController:imageViewPickerController
                   animated:NO
                 completion:NULL];
```

SOLUTION:

I found the solution: it was both merging in Visput's suggestion, and fguchelaar's. I then removed the `btnView.alpha = 0.3` and replaced it with `btnView.opaque = NO;` and that did the trick. Messed around with colors and now my overlay is working perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried setting the frame of `btnView` to non-zero? `UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewPickerController.view.bounds];` for instance?

Comment: Made a change similar to this and still no dice. I updated the OP once more (2nd time) with my updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame of your overlay view has zero size:

```
UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Change it like this and you will see it:

```
UIView *btnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024];
```

**Update:**
Also enable `clipsToBounds` flag: `btnView.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Comment: I actually realized this a couple minutes before you commented, however, it didn't fix it. I updated the OP to reflect this change.

Comment: Still no dice, unfortunately. Modified OP once more with changed code

Comment: @mattchue Actually overlayView is applied. Try to change it's alpha: `btnView.alpha = 0.9;` camera view will become almost black.